# Replace subexpression in equality proof in Idris

Tags: dependent-type, idris, theorem-proving

As an exercise in Idris I am trying to prove this property:

```
multCancel : (a:Nat) -> (b:Nat) -> (c:Nat) -> (S a) * b = (S a) * c -> b = c
```

I came to the conclusion, that as an itermediate step, I need to prove something like this:

```
lemma1 : {x:Nat} -> {y:Nat} -> {z:Nat} -> (x + x) + (x * z) = (y + y) + (y * z) -> (x * (S (S z))) = (y * (S (S z)))
lemma1 {x=x} {y=y} {z=z} prf = ?todo
```

Of course, I already have proven that:

```
plusDouble : (a:Nat) -> (a + a) = a*2
plusDouble a =
  rewrite multCommutative a 2 in
  rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral a in Refl
```

So I believe I basically only need to replace `(x + x)` by `(x*2)` and then invoke distributivity in order to prove `lemma1` . I don't know how to do this replacement. 
I thought I could simply do something like

```
rewrite plusDouble x in ...
```

But that apparently won't work because the subexpression I want to replace is in `prf` and in in the goal.

Is there some general approach to this? Or something you would recommend in this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out that I do not have to always simplify the goal using rewrite rules but I can instead expand it to match the proof I get as argument.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "expand"? I have a similar problem, so I would be interested in a more detailed answer.

Comment: I mean that the left hand side of the equality used as rewrite rule is "more complicated" in some sense. For example, you can do `rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral right in someProofMatchingRight` (this is what I call simplification of goal) but you can also do `rewrite sym $ plusZeroRightNeutral right in someProofMatchingZeroPlusRight` (this is what I call expansion of goal). Perhaps there is a more precise terminology, idk.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite feature uses `replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y` under the hood; it is figuring out what `P` should be (as far as I understand).

To replace `x + x` with `x*2` you may use the equality `x + x = x*2` as you have. To replace `x*2` with `x + x` you may use the equality `x*2 = x + x`; that is `sym prf` in your case. You need two replacements to achieve both.

When the rewrite tool (or inference) cannot figure it out you can explicitly provide `P`, such as `replace {P = \x' => x' + (x * z) = (y + y) + (y * z)} (plusDouble x) prf`. This is particularly useful when you need to rewrite some sites of `x + x` but not all.